# Does Visual Studio have the possibility to disable extensions, which was installed per-machine?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

The "Disable" button is disabled for all per-machine extensions, on my side.

Comment: You probably need to run as Administrator

Comment: I was tried, it does not help, the "Disable" button is still hidden

Comment: You are probably looking at MSI based extensions, a very common flavor.  They cannot be disabled, only uninstalled.